# How to get the current month and the next months until next year in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I want to get the current month and the next 12 months in vanilla js. For example, upon writing this question it's April 2022, So I want to have this output:

April 2022
May 2022
June 2022
July 2022
August 2022
September 2022
October 2022
November 2022
December 2022
January 2023
February 2023
March 2023
April 2023

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1 + i;
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  if (month > 12) {
    month = month - 12;
    year = year + 1;
  }
  const nameMonth = {
    1: "Jan",
    2: "Feb",
    3: "Mar",
    4: "Apr",
    5: "May",
    6: "Jun",
    7: "Jul",
    8: "Aug",
    9: "Sep",
    10: "Oct",
    11: "Nov",
    12: "Dec",
  };
  console.log(year + " Year " + nameMonth[month] + " Month ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1 + i;
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  if (month > 12) {
    month = month - 12;
    year = year + 1;
  }
  const nameMonth = {
    1: "Jan",
    2: "Feb",
    3: "Mar",
    4: "Apr",
    5: "May",
    6: "Jun",
    7: "Jul",
    8: "Aug",
    9: "Sep",
    10: "Oct",
    11: "Nov",
    12: "Dec",
  };
  console.log(
    year + " Year " + nameMonth[month] + " Month "
  );
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. does not update the year when you cross over. see correct solution below

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).